# Getting error TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression

Tags: typescript, loopbackjs

I created a new project from loopback 4 cli (`lb4 app`)

When I open the PingController with WebStorm, I see this error in the `@get` decorator:

```
TS1241: Unable to resolve signature of method decorator when called as an expression.
```

after reading [here](https://github.com/alsatian-test/alsatian/issues/344#issuecomment-290418311) I set the target in tsconfig.json to `es2017` and it indeed removed that error, but now I'm getting this error in very import line:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module '@loopback/xxxxx'
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding `"module": "commonjs"` to the compiler options in tsconfig.json worked for me.

Also make sure to use TypeScript 3.2 or later, I think the loopback-sceleton needs it. With it, I think you shouldn't need to add the target-version, since the configuration extends from loopback.